# How much does a house cost in Skyrim? Can I get one for free?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I buy a house in Skyrim? How much do I have to pay? Can I put an alchemy table or an enchanter table in it? Do I've to solve a quest to get a house?

Comment: According to [the UESP wiki page on houses](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses), the price range is 5,000 to 25,000 gold. The page also lists some free shacks with non-respawning ("safe") containers you can use.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can buy several houses in Skyrim:

1. **Whiterun***, 5000 septims. After completing the Bleak Falls Barrow quest.
2. **Riften****, 5000 or 8000 septims. After performing several quests in Riften.
3. **Markarth****, 8000. After completing either the Main Quest or Lvl 20, Red Eagle Redoubt and some miscellaneous quests.
4. **Windhelm****, 8000 or 12000 septims. Available after completing the Stormcloak quests. Also becomes available after completion of the Imperial Army quest line. Available after completing the quest Blood on the Ice
5. **Solitude****, 25,000 septims. Available after completing a miscellaneous quest (named Elisif's Tribute) for the Jarl.
6. **Dawnstar***, free. Available after completing the Dark Brotherhood quest Hail Sithis! The Master Bedroom upgrade costs 3000 gold, purchased from Delvin Mallory, as part of a total 19,000 gold upgrade of the sanctuary.
7. **Dawnstar***, 5000 septims. Available after installing **Hearthfire**, doing the completion Waking Nightmares, and doing the completion of Kill the Giant.
8. **Markarth**, free. Available after completion of The House of Horrors.
9. **Winterhold**, free. Available upon enrolling in the College of Winterhold.
10. **Winterhold*****, free. Available upon completing the The Eye of Magnus.
11. **Morthal***, 5000 septims. Availible after installing **Hearthfire**, and completing Laid to Rest.
12. **Falkreath***, 5000 septims. Available after installing **Hearthfire**, completing Black Briar Mead, and Kill the Bandit Leader.

*House can be upgraded to have an Alchemy Lab
**House can be upgraded to have an Alchemy Lab and an Arcane Enchanter
***House has Alchemy Lab and Arcane Enchanter 
****Houses that need Hearthfire have land plot where you can create you're own house in the land by first planning it using the drafting table and creating it in the workbench. Interior workbenches are for the inside of homes.

Comment: Plus the cost for upgrades, as you can see on the Wiki page, count anywhere from 1800 (Whiterun) to 9000 (Windhelm) gold. You'll want them because they look nice, and include extra containers.

Comment: What does free Markarth house have to do with house of horrors? That abandoned house is unclean and doesn't have an enchanting or alchemy or anything else in that house.

Answer (score 2):

The house listings above is great but here is the trick to get your houses **for free**.

You do actually need the money to buy the house but all can be bought for no gold out of pocket. When you're able to buy your house, save your game in front of the person. Now look for a chest/cupboard/dresser/container close to you. Click on buy the house then click confirm. Here's where the magic happens.

Right after you confirm buying, exit out of the chat and **quickly** run to the container.
"Sprint shout" is sometimes needed to achieve this since you only have around 6 second  to achieve this. Run to container open and drop ALL your GOLD in container, then exit container. If you pulled it off after exiting the container the chat should have now timed out and you received your House Key.

Now just go back to the container and get all your Gold back. This does not trigger stealing. You can't get your house furnishings for free but hey FREE HOUSES.

Comment: I think this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: really? did you read the header? How much does a house cost in Skyrim? Can I get one for FREE? see the FREE part? i think my answer gave him that solution...

Comment: You still need the 5000k gold to begin with to be able to get the house, which really doesn't make the houses "free". However the possibility of exploiting the game by hiding the gold away before it is collected is rather smart.

Comment: @Spoike so they mean getting a house without paying, not getting a house for free since you still need the money.

Answer (score 0):

Like Wimpey, the first poster said, the minimum price for a house is 5000, and unless you use the exploiting method that Master said (that hasn't been confirmed yet, and you need all the gold anyway,) you can get a house for free.

I obtained the cheapest house that wasn't free, 5000; it's stationed in Whiterun and it comes with a storage chest. You can, of course, buy furnishings and upgrades to make it much nicer. However, to be allowed to buy this house, you must first complete the Bleak Falls Barrow quest by delivering the Dragonstone to the Jarl's Mage along the main quest.

Best of luck with your house search. Just a note that to become the Thieves Guild Guildmaster, you must own the 25,000 Septim manor in Solitude first.

Comment: I have gotten all of my houses free except for my first which was in whiterun before i figured out the trick i listed. I am the Thieves Guildmaster having gotten Solitude house for free so it did NOT effect it negatively just FYI

Comment: "Best of luck with your house search. Just a note that to become the Thieves Guild Guildmaster, you must own the 25,000 Septim manor in Solitude first." I don't know what you're talking about. This is about house costs and methods of getting them free, not about Thieves Guild stuff.