# How do you obtain the pets for sale quest on the Switch version?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim* for the Nintendo Switch, how do you obtain the pets for sale quest?

Comment: I've edited your post to have one question only to avoid being closed as 'needs more focus'. About house prices in Skyrim, see: [How much does a house cost in Skyrim? Can I get one for free?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42159/4797)

Answer (score 2):

By "Pets for Sale" quest, I'm assuming you mean the "[Pets of Skyrim](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pets_of_Skyrim_(quest))" quest (a quest to obtain multiple pets).

The [Pets of Skyrim](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pets_of_Skyrim_(quest)) quest is added by the [Pets of Skyrim](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pets_of_Skyrim) Creation Club DLC. You need to buy or upgrade to the *[Skyrim Anniversary Edition](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-anniversary-edition-switch/)*  for the Switch (which contains Pets of Skyrim, among other [Creation Club](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Creation_Club) DLCs). It can not be played on the Switch if you don't have the Anniversary Edition.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case this makes way more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [UESP entry for the Pets of Skyrim quest](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pets_of_Skyrim_(quest)), the first step in obtaining the five pets is to

> Read the For Sale notice at The Bannered Mare.

The notice will give you the first location to travel to.